# Error 404 on console when running flask app

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a flask app and try to render `index.html`. When I run the app, these errors occurs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2020 15:08:16] "GET /dim0/image1.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
...
```

Here is the code `app.py`:

```py
...
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The app structure:

```
+-- app.py
+-- static
|   +-- dim0
|       +-- image1.png
+-- templates
|   +-- index.html
+-- Procfile
+-- runtime.txt
+-- requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost a day of searching, the only thing I missed is this line `static_url_path=''`. Now it loads every file flawlessly.

```py
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
```

Answer (score 3):

`Flask` expects `templates` and NOT `template` as default folder's name to hold templates.

refer to https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=flask#flask.Flask

> **template_folder** – the folder that contains the templates that should be used by the application. Defaults to '**templates**' folder in the root path of the application.

if you want to rename that folder to `template` you need to mention that in app definition :

```
    app = Flask(
        __name__, 
        # static_url_path=None,
        # static_folder='static',
        # static_host=None,
        # host_matching=False,
        # subdomain_matching=False,
        template_folder='template',  # HERE
        # instance_path=None,
        # instance_relative_config=False,
        # root_path=None
    )
```

## update:

maybe you need to remove the `/` at the beginning in

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='dim0/image1.png') }}" alt="..">
```

Comment: typo when posting, the folder actually templates not template. my bad

Comment: how you call `/dimo/image1.png` in index.html ?

Comment: actually im using [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html) to load the image(s). its kinda dynamic, that why I messed up